# R/ggplot2: how to match legend and plot colors in overlapping area plots?

Tags: r, colors, ggplot2

I have two area plots (call them 'blue' and 'green') where the `green` is mostly under the `blue` plot, but on a very few points, it is higher than the `blue` plot. I want to use transparency say `alpha = 0.2` for both, and also be able to specify the colors for each. My problem now is that since the `green` plot is mostly under the `blue` plot, its area mostly has the *blended* color `blue` + `green` = some other color, and in only a few places shows its "true" green color. However the *legend* of course shows the `blue` plot mapped to blue and the `green` plot mapped to green. Problem is, when someone looks at the graph, they will be confused since the `green` plot mostly looks non-green (because it's overlapping with blue most of the time).

Here's my code (super simplified version of my real application).

```
df <- data.frame( date = 1:5, blue = 10, green = c(1,5,11,5,1))
df.m <- melt( df, id = 'date', variable_name = 'type' )
df.m$type <- ordered( df.m$type, c('green', 'blue'))

ggplot(df.m, aes(date,value)) +
  geom_area( aes(fill = type),  position = 'identity', alpha = 0.2) +
  scale_fill_manual ( values = c('green', 'blue') )
```

[image]

As you can see, the "true green" area of the green plot is very small, so the legend color for `green` doesn't really match the majority of the `green` plot. This is of course the right behavior by design, but I am wondering if there is some way I can get the legend colour for `green`, and the overlapping `blue+green` color to match up. One thing I did try is to transform the `blue` variable to `blue - green`, and then make the area plots *stacked* (with `position = "stack"`). This almost works but isn't quite satisfactory because the color on the dates where the new `blue` variable is negative looks strange.

Are there other ways to get the legend color for `green` and the color of the "overlapping blue/green" area to match up? Maybe a way to directly specify the legend color? Any help appreciated!

Comment: Didn't you try to choose other colors? `%)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not think defining custom colors in the legend is possible with a simple call in ggplot2, but if you do insist on specifying the colors, you might draw the plot without a legend by `opts(legend.position = "none")` and attach a separate legend by eg. using grid viewport. Package [gridExtra](http://code.google.com/p/gridextra/wiki/arrangeGrob) could also be a great resource for the latter task.

Comment: Thank you @daroczig. I may go with turning off the legend and using text-annotation to point to each area.

Comment: @Prasad Chalasani: your idea sounds a lot craftier than mine, I am definitely sure you should go that way. The only problem could be defining the optimal x,y coords to put the texts. Good luck!

Comment: I agree, the problem with text-annotation is finding a good general location for the text, that will work in all cases under consideration.