# Change alpha level of geom_point in legend on top of stat_smooth

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm running into trouble changing the alpha of my (coloured) points in the legend when I add `stat_smooth`.

```
require(ggplot2)

set.seed(1052)
dx <- runif(2000,0,10)
dy <- dx * rep(c(1,-1), each = 1000) + rnorm(2000,0,1)
dcol <- rep(c(TRUE, FALSE), each = 1000)
dd <- data.frame(x = dx, y = dy, col = dcol)

gg <- ggplot(dd) + aes(x = x, y = y, colour = col) + geom_point(alpha = 1/5)
gg
```

[image: The legend is cloudy.]

The alpha of the points carries over to the legend (making the colours hard to view), but [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5290003/how-to-set-legend-alpha-with-ggplot2) shows that you can override legend details with `guides`:

```
magic <- guides(colour = guide_legend(override.aes = list(alpha = 1))) 
gg + magic
```

[image: It's fixed!]

Cool. But when I throw in `stat_smooth`, the magic stops working.

```
gg + stat_smooth(method = "lm")
```

[image: Line is solid, but point has low alpha.]

```
gg + stat_smooth(method = "lm") + magic
```

[image: I don't know what happened here.]

How can I fix this? I would rather have the below result for the legend (white background, line and point with `alpha = 1`. (The issues seems to go away if you use `geom_line` and not `stat_smooth`)

```
gg + geom_line(alpha = 1/10) + magic
```

[image: Huh.]

Comment: This might be a bug. The problem is the standard error ribbon. If you set `se = FALSE` in `geom_smooth` things work again. What's happening is that you set `alpha` for the points, but `geom_smooth` sets another alpha for the ribbon. When you override the legend's alpha, it's being applied to both the points and the grey fill. Haven't figured out a workaround yet...

Comment: ...one option is to set `show_guide = FALSE` in `geom_smooth`, but then you lose the lines in the legend.

Comment: try `stat_smooth(method = "lm", se=FALSE)` if you don't need SE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to get legend key with just line and point and without background then you can add `fill=NA` inside the `override.aes=` - this will remove grey fill of legend key that is set due to confidence intervals of `stat_smooth()` (`se=TRUE`). Then with `theme()` and `legend.key=` you can change background to white.

```
ggplot(dd, aes(x = x, y = y, colour = col)) + geom_point(alpha = 1/5)+
  stat_smooth(method = "lm")+
  guides(colour = guide_legend(override.aes = list(alpha = 1,fill=NA))) + 
  theme(legend.key=element_rect(fill="white"))
```

[image]