# Remove point transparency in ggplot2 legend

Tags: r, ggplot2

In ggplot2, transparency that is defined in geom_XXX is reflected in the legend. For example:

```
df <- data.frame(x=runif(10000),  z=ifelse(runif(10000) > 0.5, 'a', 'b')); df$y <- runif(10000); df$y[df$z == 'b'] <- cos(df$x[df$z == 'b']*10)
ggplot(df) + geom_point(aes(x, y, color=z), alpha=0.1)
```

Gives the following result:

[image: what we have]

Since the points are very transparent, they are hardly seen on the legend. I would like to remove point transparency from the legend, so that the graph looks like this:

[image: what I want]

How is this possible?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You can use function `guides()` and `override.aes=` to set alpha value just for legend entries.

```
ggplot(df) + geom_point(aes(x, y, color=z), alpha=0.1)+
  guides(colour = guide_legend(override.aes = list(alpha=1)))
```

Comment: wasn't aware of this mechanism. Quick search for override.aes gave several more examples: http://stackoverflow.com/q/16356052/17523  and http://stackoverflow.com/q/5290003/17523 which is a duplicate of this question.